# Optimize pixel image comparison using emgu cv libraries instead of for loops

Tags: c#, opencv

- I'm working on an Invisible watermarking c# project.
- Requirement is to embed a watermark image into a cover image based on
  comparing each watermark image pixel with each cover image pixel
  based on a threshold value.
- I have used 4 for-loops for iterating through watermark image and
  cover image. But it works only for much smaller image (ie: 30x30
  pixels), i need to optimize it for bigger images and to find the best
  fitting place of watermark pixel in cover image location.
- I know this is not the optimum way, instead of for loops i need any suggestion of best library to use in **Emgu cv in c#** to do these easily.
- Please suggest a way to optimize my piece of code for bigger images. Thanks.

  ```
     // iterate through watermark_img
              for (int x = 0; x < watermark_img.Height; x++)
              {
                  for (int y = 0; y < watermark_img.Width; y++)
                  {
                      //iterate through cover image
                      for (int i = 0; i < cover.Height; i++)
                      {
                          for (int j = 0; j < cover.Width; j++)
                          {
                              Bgr pixel_watermark = watermark_img[x, y];
                              Bgr pixel_cover = cover[i, j];

                              //get watermark pixel color values
                               double b_wm = pixel_watermark.Blue;
                               double g_wm = pixel_watermark.Green;
                               double r_wm = pixel_watermark.Red;

                              //get cover image pixel color values
                              double b_cov = pixel_cover.Blue;
                              double g_cov = pixel_cover.Green;
                              double r_cov = pixel_cover.Red;

                              //diff
                              double b_diff = Math.Abs(b_wm - b_cov);
                              double g_diff = Math.Abs(g_wm - g_cov);
                              double r_diff = Math.Abs(r_wm - r_cov);

                              //determine threshold ====== 7 (last 3 bits)

                              int threshold = 7;
                              if ((b_diff <= threshold) && (g_diff <= threshold) && (r_diff <= threshold))
                              {
                                  flag = true;
                                  count_hit[cnt - 1]++;
                                  //MessageBox.Show("No of pixels qualified for embedding =\t", count_hit.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                              }

                              else
                              {
                                  flag = false;
                                  count_miss[cnt - 1]++;
                                  // MessageBox.Show("Pixel count lesser than threshold =\t", count_miss.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                              }
  ```

Comment: Why are you nesting 4 for loops instead of using two for loops and operating on corresponding pixels in the two images? Or does your watermarking require you to relate the top-left of one image to a pixel as far away as the bottom-right on the other image?

Comment: yes, i am using two loops for one a single image to run over whole image considering co-ordinates (x,y). Can u suggest a way to replace for loops with any inbuilt Emgu cv function in image processing?

Comment: So it looks like the locations of the pixels don't matter- just which colors are present/absent in both images?

Comment: No Sir, As the next step, i need to do the embedding. Here i find the suitable place for embedding by comparing with threshold. So i need an optimization to find the best cover image location for embedding the correct watermark pixel too.

Comment: Copy the `Image<>.Data` to a `byte[ , , ]` to loop over. I have found that it is much faster.

Comment: @KDecker, Hope u meant the following change. But still it doesn't give any improved output for bigger images. Please suggest clearly if u meant something else.   `byte[] watermark_arr = {    watermark_img.Data[x, y, 0], watermark_img.Data[x, y, 1], watermark_img.Data[x, y, 2] 
                                                ...
                                    byte[] cover_arr = {    cover.Data[i, j, 0], cover.Data[i, j, 1], cover.Data[i, j, 2] 
                                                       };

                                   ...

Comment: Just copy the image data to a byte array. `Image<Bgr, Byte> myImage` load something into the image, then copy its `Data` to loop over `byte[,,] myImageData = myImage.Data`, now loop over `myImageData`.